# Remove currency symbol, 1000's separator and standardise the decimal notation

Tags: c#, regex

I am trying to create a regular expression to remove formatting of financial values received in a string.

I have written code to remove the currency symbol, but am having problems removing the 1000's separator as it can be a any one of the following: `, . '`

This is what I have so far:

```
string pattern = @"\p{Sc}*(\s?\d+[.,]?\d*)\p{Sc}*";
string replacement = "$1";
string input = "here are the text values: $16,000.32 12.19 £16.29 €18.000,29  €18,29 ₹17,00,00,00,000.00";
string result = Regex.Replace(input, pattern, replacement);
Console.WriteLine(result);
```

How can I modify my code to also replace the 1000's separator and standardise the decimal notation?

Comment: [NumberStyles](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.globalization.numberstyles?view=netframework-4.7.2) is your friend

Comment: "I had a problem and then I used regular expressions. Now I have two problems" - Regular expressions aren't a good fit for this problem.

Comment: The duplicate won't answer this question directly. But yes, he shouldn't use regex to parse decimals. Instead you should take the long route: split the values by space, then use `decimal.TryParse(v, NumberStyles.AllowCurrencySymbol | NumberStyles.Any, c, out decimal d)` to parse them. You can store all allowed `CultureInfo`s in a list/array and use a loop/LINQ to pass them to `decimal.TryParse`. If it returned `true` you have the decimal value. Then use `decimal.ToString(format)` to get your desired format. You build the result string with `String.Join`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use such pattern: `(\d)[.,'](\d{3})`.

Explanation: it will match any thousand separator you listed with `[.,']` if it's preceeded by digit and followed by three digits.

Preceeding and following digits are captured into first and second capturing group, so you just need to replace match with `\1\2`, meaning you omit the separator.

**Note**: it would also remove decimal separator, if decimal part is longer than three digits.